# How to pass argument into NPM script without double dashes

Tags: npm

```
//package.json    
"scripts": {
    "run-tests": "node scripts/run-tests.js"
}
```

When I run my test suite using `npm run run-tests --env=integration --variant=alpha`, I get undefined argument values:

```
//run-tests.js
console.log(argv.env) //undefined
console.log(argv.variant) //undefined
```

However, when I run my test suite with two dashes (`--`) `npm run run-tests -- --env=integration --variant=alpha`, I get my argument values:

```
//run-tests.js
console.log(argv.env) //integration
console.log(argv.variant) //alpha
```

Can I somehow get my argument values in `run-test.js` without using `--`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the discussion in [this](https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/5518) pull request, I believe the answer to your question is no :(

However, a workaround is to specify your arguments in the package.json file in the scripts block. This is preferred in a CI/CD context, as you want less coupling with your CI/CD provider.

In package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "test:int:a": "node scripts/run-tests.js --env=integration --variant=alpha",
    "test:int:b": "node scripts/run-tests.js --env=integration --variant=bravo"
}
```

Then on command-line:

```
npm run test:int:a
```

If you are going more for a command-line tool, I suggest looking into creating a
CLI tool with node.js, such as [this](https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/scripting-with-node/) example.

Comment: This is unfortunate that they couldn't come up with something better. PNPM figured it out the best: https://pnpm.io/cli/run. Wish npm would follow suit.